# iPhone - Replacing line breaks in my TextView with <br />?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, line-breaks

I am trying to convert `lineBreaks` in my `UITextView` to `<br />` tags, 
why does the following line crash? It complains about `[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]` because when I pass it a normal string it works fine

```
[myMutableString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:
  [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] withString:@"<br />"];

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFCharacterSet length]: unrecognized selector sent to 
instance 0x7b1cc80'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `NSCharacterSet` is not a `NSString`.So you're passing a wrong argument.
If you have only newline "\n" characters you can use:

```
[myMutableString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" 
                                           withString:@"<br />"];
```

If you have also "\r" and "\lf" you can try something like this (untested)

```
NSRange range;
while((range = [myMutableString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:
                [NSCharacterSet newlineCharcaterSet]]).location != NSNotFound) {
    [myMutableString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@"<br />"];
}
```